# Regarding creating an image out of data in RGB form stored in a CSV

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Alright so I am a beginner with python. I know this is a very small problem. 
I am trying to create an image using python from some data which is in the format r="some value",b="some value",c="some value" stored in columns of a CSV file. How can I do that? Also would like the rows vs columns of the formed image variable.

The data looks like this

```
 r=ff g=ff b=fe
 r=05 g=80 b=00
 r=00 g=40 b=50
 r=80 g=04 b=05
 r=48 g=00 b=00
 r=05 g=50 b=00
 r=00 g=0a b=80
 r=a0 g=00 b=08
 r=0a g=00 b=00
 r=00 g=80 b=a0
 r=00 g=08 b=0a
 r=a0 g=00 b=00
 r=1f g=a0 b=f0
 r=3f g=14 b=00
 r=ff g=03 b=ff
 r=ff g=ff b=ff
 r=ff g=ff b=ff
```

Comment: How do you know what color is supposed to be where in the image? What libraries are you currently using to read / process the data?

Comment: Please share the CSV and everything you know about it - such as the image height and width in pixels.